# How to display big video files chunk by chunk on frontend using html5 video tag?

Tags: html, html5-video

I got 3 static videos on frontend, all of them takes approximately 21-22mb in size.

```
<video autoplay="true" src="videos/video1.webm"></video>
<video autoplay="true" src="videos/video2.webm"></video>
<video autoplay="true" src="videos/video3.webm"></video>
```

Their html autoplay attribute is set to true, so they need to be played immediately after the get request, or in my situation, after 3-4 seconds of a maximum delay. But the problem is, webpage starts playing them only after they fully downloaded.

**How can i make a buffering for each of them?**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the video to progressively download - i.e. to start playing while the download continues.

This simplest way to do this is to ensure your server hosting the video supports range requests. If you were using mp4 files you would also need to make sure that the videos had the header data at the start, but this is not an issue for webm.

Once your server supports range requests then your browser video element should automatically request the video in chunks and start playing as soon as it has enough to start, assuming you set it to autoplay or hit the play button.

You can see more about Range Requests at the link below including the following easy check to see if your server support this:

> curl -I https://yourVideoUrl

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests)

If you get a result that suggests Range Request are not supported it is quietly like a configuration issue on the server so speak to your server admin.